# Logical delete from DB

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have a complex schema with many entitites and relations.I want to define a logical delete operation which can be undone. I've considered adding 'isDeleted' flag to every table, but it seems bug-proned to me.
I've also considered adding an archive schema which is similar to the original schema, and on every delete operation to move the data there.That seems to require a lot of code to write for the "delete" and "undelete" operations (espacially since I want to emulate on delete casade for the logical delte).

Finally, I'm not sure where to handle the events of logical delete
I'm using EF so I can do it in code, or maybe I can use the delete trigger in he DB.

I would appreiciate any recomendations on how to implement the logical delete in an elegant way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every company I worked for has always used a logical delete flag and managed it through code. Adding an archive schema is a huge overhead and IMO its added elegancy (both coding and performance wise) doesn't worth the extra effort.

Comment: The downside for the deleted flag is that while you save effort in the delete operation you need to add the isDeleted = false check to every query.

Comment: @omer schleifer A 'deleted' column in every DB which is part of your indexes and default in your query scopes is far more easy and you put the business logic in your code, not in your database. What if you want to restore or just view deleted records? So I doubt any other attempt is worth the overload and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an OLTP database, I don't have issue using the IsDeleted flag.  If you are worried about performance, I will continue using the IsDeleted flag and move it to archive through a batch process, not online.

One thing that I always keep in mind to avoid over-architecting something - It's not a problem unless it's a problem.